# streamparse submit issues to localhost

Tags: apache-storm

When I am trying to submit streamparse topology to the cluster (here I am using localhost as nimbus and worker in conf.json file of streamparse) I am getting this error.

```
(homeenv)nandaraj@nandaraj-ThinkCentre-Edge72:~/streamparse/wordcount$ sparse submit -n wordcount -e prod
[localhost] Executing task '_create_or_update_virtualenv'

Fatal error: Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host: localhost), but input would be ambiguous in parallel mode

Aborting.
Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host: localhost), but input would be ambiguous in parallel mode

Fatal error: One or more hosts failed while executing task '_create_or_update_virtualenv'

Aborting.
One or more hosts failed while executing task '_create_or_update_virtualenv'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do following to fix the issue.
Please check config.json

```
{
    "serializer": "json",
    "topology_specs": "topologies/",
    "virtualenv_specs": "virtualenvs/",

    "envs": {
        "prod": {

            "user": "testuser",
            "ssh_password": "password",
            "nimbus": "localhost",
            "workers": ["localhost"],
            "log": {
                "path": "/var/log",
                "max_bytes": 1000000,
                "backup_count": 10,
                "level": "info"
            },
            "virtualenv_root": "/work/virtualenv"
        }
    }
}
```

"user" and "ssh_password" must be valid in os.
In my case, I have been doing this in Ubantu.
you can check ssh service like this.

```
sudo service ssh status
```

if ssh service is not started, you have to start it first.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
sudo service ssh start
```

Answer (score 0):

I have meet the same problem as you, and I figured it out by myself.
Maybe your "user" configure in config.json is "storm" or something not in your host, so change is to "root".

Answer (score 0):

By default streamparse uses ssh for communication, so you will need to provide user and password on your config.